# ValueError: Expected object or value when using Panda ro read json file

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to read a json file with Pandas

```
import pandas as pd


sns.set(style="whitegrid", color_codes=True)

path = "../data/db_complete.log"
df = pd.read_json(path, orient='records', lines=True)

lift_df = df.loc[:, ["aisle", "lift_finish_retrieve_time"]]
interval = 3600

df_order = df[["parent_order", "release", "shuttle_start_retrieve_time","finish_pick_time"]]

print(df.columns)
```

When i run it, i get this Error Message:

```
ValueError: Expected object or value
```

I already tried to change the format of the given path in several ways, it never worked...

Comment: which line gives that error? Please include the entire traceback please.

Comment: It's likely `pd. read_json`. That file of yours may not be a good json file. Try using the `json` module to load it first and then make a dataframe from there.

Comment: I tried to load it with json first and then make a pandas dataframe, but although the document definitely is there and i tried hundrets of inputs for the path i still get  
  
`with open(path) as log_file:`
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '..\\data\\db_complete.log'`